# Are there codes for calculating column's average using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to calculate every city's average enternum (groupby city) using spark RDD and dataframes. (I want all two ways)

Furthermore, how can I ignore first two header rows when I calculate average?

I've tried using RDD and dataframes. But all were unsuccessful.

This is input csv file.

> city,type,enterdate,enternum
>
> 縣市,軍種類別,入營日期,入營人數
>
> 臺北市,陸軍,1040713,150
>
> 臺北市,陸軍,1040813,210
>
> 臺北市,陸軍,1040827,180
>
> 臺北市,陸軍,1040915,300

This is python code:

```
if __name__=="__main__":

#RDD
rdd = sc.textFile("junren.csv").flatMap(lambda line: line.split(",")[3])
rdd.mean().show()

#datefrmae
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.load('junren.csv',format='com.databricks.spark.csv',header='true',inferSchema='true',encoding='UTF-8') 

df.mean("enternum").show()
#df.groupBy('city').agg(avg(col('enternum'))).show()
```

this is error for dataframe:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\eclipse-workspace\demo2\src\Test7.py", line 49, in
>   
>       df.mean("enternum").show()   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py",
>   line 1300, in **getattr**
>       "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.**class**.**name**, name)) AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'mean'

This is error for RDD:

> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
>   line 377, in main   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
>   line 372, in process   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 2499, in pipeline_func
>       return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 2499, in pipeline_func
>       return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 352, in func
>       return f(iterator)   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 1065, in 
>       return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [StatCounter(i)]).reduce(redFunc)   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\statcounter.py",
>   line 43, in **init**
>       self.merge(v)   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\statcounter.py",
>   line 47, in merge
>       delta = value - self.mu
>
> 19/05/15 04:46:01 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1
>   times; aborting job Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\eclipse-workspace\demo2\src\Test7.py", line 40, in
>   
>       rdd.mean().show()   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 1202, in mean
>       return self.stats().mean()   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 1065, in stats
>       return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [StatCounter(i)]).reduce(redFunc)   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 844, in reduce
>       vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 816, in collect
>       sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py",
>   line 1257, in **call**   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0
>   in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver):
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
>   line 377, in main   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
>   line 372, in process   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 2499, in pipeline_func
>       return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 2499, in pipeline_func
>       return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 352, in func
>       return f(iterator)   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 1065, in 
>       return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [StatCounter(i)]).reduce(redFunc)   File
>   "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\statcounter.py",
>   line 43, in **init**
>       self.merge(v)   File "C:\Users\pc95\Downloads\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\statcounter.py",
>   line 47, in merge
>       delta = value - self.mu TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Answer (score 0):

From the last line of the error, I believe that your column is of type 'String'. Hence I am converting it into an 'Integer' type using SQL cast method.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

#Entire column average
df.select(F.avg(df.enternum.cast(IntegerType()))).show()

#City wise average
df.groupby('City').agg(F.avg(df.enternum.cast(IntegerType())).alias('Average_enternum')).show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but I could not import F.avg           
How can I import spark.sql.functions.avg ?

Comment: @Gyu-lim Shim, the first line 'from pyspark.sql import functions as F' imports the entire SQL functions package. Alternatively, you can import only the AVG method by replacing the first line by 'from pyspark.sql.functions import avg' and just use 'avg' instead of 'F.avg' in the further part of the code. Hope this was helpful!